# MATLAB assign rank to values in a matrix in ascending/descending order

Tags: matlab, sorting, ranking

I have a `60x6` matrix `X` where column 1 is an index and columns 2 to 6 are data for that particular index. I'd like to assign ranks to each value in the data columns, such that columns 2 though 5 are ranked in descending order (highest value is ranked 1, lowest value ranked 60) and column 6 is ranked in descending order (lowest value ranked 1, highest ranked 60), but so that the row order is maintained according the the index (column 1). Rank ties are assigned a rank equal to the average of their positions in the ascending order of the values.

I've looked through a number of suggestions ([here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/08/21/reversal-of-a-sort/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514166/ranking-of-a-cell-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448759/sort-in-matlab-and-assign-ranking)) and tried my own version:

```
[~,Z1] = sort(X(:,2),'descend');
[~,Z2] = sort(X(:,3),'descend');
[~,Z3] = sort(X(:,4),'descend');
[~,Z4] = sort(X(:,5),'descend');
[~,Z5] = sort(X(:,6));
```

but none seem to work the way I want them to. So for

```
    X =

        1    0.9503    0.5646    0.3785    0.5468   -0.0161     
        2    0.9430    0.5728    0.3320    0.6693   -0.0161
        3    0.5305    0.2719    0.1545    0.3480    0.0042
        4    0.8588    0.5816    0.3429    0.6477   -0.0158
        5    0.9391    0.5984    0.3362    0.6054   -0.0161
        6    0.3780    0.2307    0.0906    0.3387    0.0054
```

I need

```
    Ans = 

         1   1   4   1   4   2
         2   2   3   4   1   2
         3   5   5   5   5   5
         4   4   2   2   2   4
         5   3   1   3   3   2
         6   6   6   6   6   6
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a somewhat clumsy, but workable solution to my problem.

It involves extracting, sorting and assigning ranks to each column of data separately, then re-combining the ranks in another table.

```
Arank = sortrows(X(:,1:2),-2);       % sort data in descending (or ascending) order
Arank(:,3)=1:60;                     % assign rank
Arank = sortrows(Arank,1);           % re-sort by index
% % same process is applied individually to each column
Allranks = horzcat(Arank(:,[1,3]), Brank(:,3),... 
Crank(:,3), Drank(:,3), Erank(:,3)); % combine all ranks sorted by index
```

However, altogether this adds up to 20 lines of code, so any more elegant alternatives would be very well received!